# Blackberry Position:fixed css does not work

Tags: html, css, jquery-mobile, blackberry-jde

I have created an app for blackberry Os6.0 and android using rho mobile and i want to use a fix header and footer in to it. I created for this a css using **position:fixed; top:0px;** . It won't work in blackberry but its run well in android. It scroll with the page and when stop scrolling it again fixed on to exact position in blackberry... my other css are working fine and there is no error..

Please Help me to fix this problem..

Comment: Any one please help me on this problem....

Answer (score 0):

In tags I see jQuery mobile so you can [use it](http://jquerymobile.com/test/docs/toolbars/bars-fixed.html)

> Fixed toolbars
>   In browsers that support CSS position: fixed (most desktop browsers, iOS5+, Android 2.2+, BlackBerry 6, and others), toolbars that use the "fixedtoolbar" plugin will be fixed to the top or bottom of the viewport, while the page content scrolls freely in between. In browsers that don't support fixed positioning, the toolbars will remain positioned in flow, at the top or bottom of the page.
>
> To enable this behavior on a header or footer, add the
>   data-position="fixed" attribute to a jQuery Mobile header or footer
>   element.
>
> Fixed header markup example:

```
<div data-role="header" data-position="fixed">
    <h1>Fixed Header!</h1>
</div>
```